# Install gcc-c++ on CentOS without yum

Tags: gcc, centos

Can I install gcc++ on CentOS 6.x without `yum install gcc-c++ ....' ?

Is there any .tar or .rpm package available for download?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yum will install rpm from it's repository.

So I don't understand why you want to avoid yum, it will solve dependencies and install them as well.

However, here is official RPM repository mirror (one of many): 
http://centos.arminco.com/5/os/i386/CentOS/

Here is list of all mirrors : http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=30

You will need at least 3 RPMs:

- gcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm
- gcc-c++-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm
- libgcc-4.4.6-3.el6.i686.rpm

For compilation of C/C++ you will also need libstdc++, glibc, etc

When you run

```
yum install gcc
```

Everything is done

As you did not specified architecture I assume i386, but URL is very similar for x86_64:

http://centos.arminco.com/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Like you said @rkosegi, **"yum install .."** is great, but not easy or suitable for choosing another versions of the things to use. Hence, it may be newer or older than its store on the repositories. And those vesions may needed from some applications or libraries as dependency.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install it as a local user (or as a superuser)

GNU GSRC provides an easy way to do so

Link: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/

After installation via bzr, simply do these:

```
./bootstrap
./configure --prefix=~/local
make -C gnu/gcc   
(or make -C gnu/gcc MAKE_ARGS_PARALLEL="-jN" to speed up for a N-core system) 
make -C gnu/gcc install
```

Comment: To get gsrc it is better to run: `bzr checkout http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/r/gsrc/trunk gsrc`. As the example they provide times out.